# iOS swift: Image from label in TabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a gray circle with name initials indie of it. And use it as tabBarItem image.

This is the function that I use to create the circle, and it almost works, as you can see in the image below, but it's a square not a circle:

```
static func createAvatarWithInitials(name: String, surname: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let initialsLabel = UILabel()
        initialsLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        initialsLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        initialsLabel.text = "\(name.characters.first!)\(surname.characters.first!)"
        initialsLabel.textAlignment = .center
        initialsLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74.0/255, green: 77.0/255, blue: 78.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        initialsLabel.layer.cornerRadius = size/2

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(initialsLabel.frame.size, false, scale)

        initialsLabel.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        return image
}
```

and this is how I call it inside the viewDidLoad of the tabBarController:

```
if index == positionForProfileItem {
                    tabBarItem.image = UIImage.createAvatarWithInitials(name: "John", surname: "Doe", size: CGFloat(20))
}
```

but I got an empty squared rectangle in the tab bar.. And I can't figure it out the reason, any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure `createAvatarWithInitials` return a right image?

Comment: if I use it in a uiimageview it returns the image as you can see in the question, the first one. If I use it in the ab bar i have the second image result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIImage withRenderingMode` method returns a new image. It does not modify the sender.

Change the last two lines to just one:

```
return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

But that is not what you wish to do. Since you want a template image of a circle with the text in the middle, you need to do the following:

```
static func createAvatarWithInitials(name: String, surname: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: size, height: size), false, 0)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Draw an opague circle
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
    circle.fill()

    // Setup text
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let text = "\(name.characters.first!)\(surname.characters.first!)"
    let textSize = (text as NSString).size(withAttributes: [ .font: font ])

    // Erase text
    ctx.setBlendMode(.clear)
    let textRect = CGRect(x: (size - textSize.width) / 2, y: (size - textSize.height) / 2, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
    (text as NSString).draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: [ .font: font ])

    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: thank you, now it shows, but I would like to have it asTemplate and if I use .alwaysTemplate i can't see anything. Suggestion? also it is not circular, suggestion? :D

Comment: When creating a template image for a tab bar item, the colors are irrelevant, only the alpha values matter. Since you make the whole image opaque, it comes out as a gray square.

Comment: ok, but if I remove the background color, now I can see the letters but not the circle. I think I should cut of the letters from the circle. Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to start with an empty, transparent content. Then draw a circle. Then use the text to erase that part of the circle.

Comment: i really don't know how to make it :p

Comment: wohoaaaa amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add clipsToBounds=YES on your label for cornerRadius to have efect on your screen shoot, and also try to increase a little bit the size of your image from 20 to 30.

Comment: great thank you, any suggestion on how use it as template?